# Velocity Templates variables and methods. Why does *this* syntax work and *that* syntax doesn't?

Tags: java, velocity, pojo

I am new to Spring MVC and Velocity Templates, but I am using them for a project and had some questions. Basically, I'm using some legacy code as my template, but the syntax in the legacy code isn't working for me and I'm not sure why. Our team has a public class called AdminData which looks something like:

```
    public class AdminData { 
            private long property1; 

            public void setProperty1 (long property1) { 
                    this.property1 = property1; 
            } 

            public long getProperty1() { 
                    return property1; 
            }
```

And Java code which looks like this:

```
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("view"); 
    AdminData data = new AdminData(); 

    ... // set some properties of data

    model.addObject("data", data); 
    return model;
```

then in our Velocity Template we reference properties of the data object like so:

```
    ${data.property1}
```

and the value is correctly displayed on the page. Then we have another class called AdminFeatures which looks like:

```
    public class AdminFeatures { 
            private boolean property2; 

            public void setProperty2(boolean property2) { 
                    this.property2 = property2; 
            } 

            public boolean getProperty2() { 
                    return property2; 
            }
```

with essentially the same Java code for setting up the model and view as we used for AdminData. The problem I'm running into is that when I try to reference property2 in AdminFeatures in the same way like:

```
    ${data.property2}
```

I am unable to print out the value of the variable. However if I use the syntax:

```
    $data.getProperty2()         // ... or ${data.getProperty2()}
```

then I am able to print the value of the property. Does this have something to do with difference between boolean vs. Boolean in Java? Or the fact the property1 is a long while property2 is a boolean?

Thank you.

Comment: For a property you should have an `is*` method not a `get*` method.

Answer (score 0):

Is because `property2` is a boolean. The standard method convention for getter/setter for a boolean type are of the form **isProperty** and setProperty.

So your AdminFeatures class should be:

public class AdminFeatures { 
        private boolean property2;

```
    public void setProperty2(boolean property2) { 
            this.property2 = property2; 
    } 

    public boolean isProperty2() { 
            return property2; 
    }
```